# Why is it necessary to import Scanner in both main and separate class?

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I created a basic calculator program using two classes, Main and Calculator. One of my methods in the Calculator class takes in a Scanner object as its parameter. I tried to delete the Scanner import from this class but IntelliJ puts it back automatically every time. Why does this class need the Scanner import if Scanner is already imported in main?

Comment: Each class is required to provide it's own imports, unlike something like C, the java files are not "copied" into a single entity and compiled, instead, they are compiled individually (generate separate class files instead of a single .o file)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That doesn't happen in C either.

Comment: @user207421 The how does C do it?  Or am thinking of another language?

Comment: @MadProgrammer It doesn't. Every source file has to #include its own includes.

Comment: @user207421 Long time since I did C and I could be (very) wrong, but does the imports from one file carry over?  ie A imports C, B imports A, can B indirectly reference C? Not really an issue, just curious

Comment: In C, there are separate 'header' files, distinct from the implementation.  You #include a header into the files that need it.  It is (logically) as if the file content were literally copied in at the point of #include.  So if A.h #includes C.h, and B.h or B.c #includes A.h, then the definitions of C.h are available in B.h or B.c.

Comment: @MadProgrammer No. There are no imports in C, only `#include`s. Don't know what you're talking about frankly.

Comment: @passer-by *"as if the file content were literally copied in at the point "* which is probably what I'm eluding to

Answer (score 1):

You don't **need** to import anything. To use a class, it is sufficient that it can be found via your classpath, or implicitly for classes in the 'java' namespace. I view it as importing **names**, not importing classes (this is possibly not the way the language spec describes it).

'import' just allows you to refer to classes (etc.) by simple names, avoiding the need to type fully-qualified class names.

Here is using `Scanner` without import. This is the entire program.

```
class n {
  public static void main(String... a) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.printf(" => %d\n", n);
  }
}
```

So, you 'import' when you need to use the class in a particular file, and don't feel like doing all the typing.

I don't use IntelliJ so cannot comment why it might fight you.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, imports are per file, so it is expected. If you need to use a Y class in n different files (in a different package) you will need to import it in each file. Some other useful details.

1. You can use `package.*` to import all classes in a package.
2. Is not necessary to import classes when used from the same package.
3. You can use `import static java.lang.Math.*;` to import static members of a class.